# Update a table using a case expression when the results are NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case

I have created a helper temp table which stores the results of a query.  Sometimes this query returns 1, 2, or 3 rows.  If there is data in the table, I need to use it to update a different table to those value(s).  If there are no results at all *or* there is only 1 or 2 rows, I need to set the value to something else.

I am having trouble setting up this query.

What I need it to do is change the NULL in #ForExcel to a blank value ('') when there are no data in the helper table.  In my first case, both #ForExcel.ExcelRow=15 and 16 ColumnF should be '' (not NULL).

In my second case, only #ForExcel.ExcelRow=16 should be '' (not NULL)

So far I have

```
CREATE TABLE #ForExcel (ExcelRow int, ColumnE varchar(max), ColumnF varchar(max))
DECLARE @i int=1
 WHILE @i <=16
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #ForExcel VALUES (@i, NULL, NULL)
        SELECT @i=@i+1
     END

CREATE TABLE #rpoB_helper (RowNumber int, MyDesiredValue varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #rpoB_helper VALUES (1, 'MyValue')

UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='rpoB',    ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS  NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE         MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh  WHERE  RowNumber=1 AND  ExcelRow=14 
UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='',          ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS NULL  THEN ''       ELSE MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh WHERE  RowNumber=2 AND  ExcelRow=15 
UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='',          ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS NULL  THEN ''       ELSE MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh WHERE   RowNumber=3 AND   ExcelRow=16 

SELECT * FROM #ForExcel

--now add a row to see with two rows
INSERT INTO #rpoB_helper VALUES (2, 'AnotherValue')   

UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='rpoB',    ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS  NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh  WHERE  RowNumber=1 AND  ExcelRow=14 
UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='',          ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS NULL  THEN ''       ELSE MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh WHERE  RowNumber=2 AND  ExcelRow=15 
UPDATE #ForExcel SET ColumnE='',          ColumnF=(CASE WHEN MyDesiredValue IS NULL  THEN ''       ELSE MyDesiredValue END) FROM #rpoB_helper rh WHERE   RowNumber=3 AND   ExcelRow=16 

SELECT * FROM #ForExcel
```

Comment: Of the six update statements here only three of them will do anything at all. The first one in the first set of updates. The second and third don't do anything because there are no rows in #rpoB_helper that meet the where predicates. Since no rows meet the predicates the update fires and you would see 0 row(s) affected.

Comment: Not really sure what you are expecting to happen here. Perhaps an explanation of the desired results would make this more clear.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear.  When no rows meet the condition, I would like to update the NULL to ''

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join in your update statement for this to work the way you want. Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
UPDATE e SET 
    ColumnE = case when rh.RowNumber is null then '' else 'rpoB' end
    , ColumnF = CASE WHEN rh.RowNumber IS NULL THEN '' ELSE rh.MyDesiredValue END
FROM #ForExcel e
left join #rpoB_helper rh on rh.RowNumber = e.ExcelRow
```

Comment: This works except if there is nothing in #rpoB_helper.  Sometimes the helper table does not have any data because the query which inserts into the helper table does not have any results.  Is there a way to update the NULLs when there is nothing in the helper table?

Comment: This would update any row in the #ForExcel table even if there are no rows in the helper table.